# Can we get rid of the "teamwork" tag?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

The [teamwork](/questions/tagged/teamwork) tag is used in 151 questions and doesn't seem to add value to questions. Some of the questions with this tag should be closed, others would be just as helpful without this tag. The tag wiki states:

> Groups of people working cooperatively to complete a task.

Hmm. Is this a candidate for burnination?

**Update:**

I noticed that the revision history for the tag wiki includes [this revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/5111224/3), which was later [rolled back](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/5111224/4) by Shog9. I couldn't find anything on meta about this particular tag, but is there some reason this *shouldn't* be removed?

Comment: The Great Cleanup went over like a ton of bricks, thus the changing of the tag wiki.  The tag is still worth being cleaned up, of course.  Don't just go and remove it, chances are that the questions it contains are horrible and worth closing and/or removing entirely.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem that useful anymore, since most of those questions aren't on-topic for Stack Overflow, but there are old questions out there that are historical that it applies to.  I think you could probably synonym it to [project-management](/questions/tagged/project-management), or something along those lines.

Comment: I would dearly love to destroy [tag:project-management] as well... and [tag:agile-project-management]

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards, yeh, but we still need it for the historicals.

Comment: Just killed the tag [on this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15614998/customize-php-graph). It is rather easy to kill because often the question is about something else and people add the project management tag because the phrase stands out when you read it.

Comment: @LeeLouviere, good, but don't forget to edit the other things in the post also (I took care of that one).

Answer (score 0):

Seems synonyms aren't enough. You need auto-burninate. For tags that are useful in history but no longer.

The tag is allowed to exist on current questions, but cannot be added to any questions going forward.